# Deleting vs. Assigning to Default Values

Tags: solidity, struct, memory

If I have a struct with many customer accounts:

```
bytes32[] public customerID;
mapping(bytes32 => CustomerAccounts) public customerAccounts;

struct CustomerAccounts{
   address customer;
   uint balance;
}
```

To delete a customer account in the struct, is it better to assign to a set of default values, like this:

```
CustomerAccounts memory blank;
customerAccounts[customerID] = blank;
```

or to use delete, as in this:

```
delete customerAccounts[customerID];
```

Or does not not really matter?

While the difference in gas is small, < 1000, I suspect in the former case, it may be still there in some ghostly form that could cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better the second option, it's cleaner and more efficient. It sets all bytes of the struct to zero, and makes the code easier to maintain.